# Dockerの開発環境をvscodeで開くには

Tags: docker, vscode

[Dockerで立ち上げた開発環境をVS Codeで開く! - Qiita](https://qiita.com/yoskeoka/items/01c52c069123e0298660)

この記事の通りで、Dockerの環境をvscodeで開きたいのですが、うまく行きません。

```
docker run -td --name centos6.8 docker.io/centos:centos6.8
```

これで作られたイメージにvscodeで接続すると以下のようなエラーが出ます

ローカル環境はmacOS Catalia 10.15.1
vscode に Remote -Container 0.83.1 をインストール済み
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
docker-composeを作らないとダメなのでしょうか？
それともCentOSはそもそもダメなのでしょうか？

調べても出てこなかったので、ご存知の方はご教示お願いいたいします。

```
Setting up container with fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3
Run: docker exec fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 /bin/sh -c (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
Run: docker cp fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3:/etc/passwd -
Run: docker exec fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 test -d /root/.vscode-server
Run: docker exec fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520
Run: docker exec fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 test -d /root/.vscode-server/extensions
Run: docker exec -w /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520 -e VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/server.sh --install-extension MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja --force
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
Run: docker exec -w / -u 0 fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 /bin/sh -c command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --system credential.helper '!f() { command -v code >/dev/null 2>&1 && code --gitCredential $*; }; f' || true
Run: docker exec -w /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520 -e SHELL=/bin/bash -e VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/server.sh --disable-user-env-probe --port 0
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
/root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/node)
Command failed: docker exec -w /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520 -e SHELL=/bin/bash -e VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server fe3c8b4390541e9a90775920c6ee567088bc6ec70f1ae08c9a78dc96c4c9a4f3 /root/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/server.sh --disable-user-env-probe --port 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) の動作要件を見ると、コンテナ側で CentOS を使う場合は `7` 以上が必要なようです。

> **System Requirements**
>   **Containers:** x86_64 Debian 8+, Ubuntu 16.04+, CentOS / RHEL 7+, Alpine Linux based containers.

エラーに出ている `gblic` はOSの種類やメジャーバージョンによってインストールできるパッケージバージョンが決まっているので、CentOS 6.8 のコンテナではうまく動かないのではないでしょうか。